# How to run a specific build step in remote run of teamcity?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

Using Teamcity command line tool how can one run a specific build step configured in the configurations?
I'm using Teamcity version 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing build in to only run some / a specific build step on a build configuration. Alternatives are either splitting up your build configuration into multiple configurations and triggering one of them or adding some scripting logic which only would work for powershell build steps, that - e.g. depending on build parameters - does not do any actual work.